# Getting values from generated inputs

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

Hello i have one input that generates " text inputs and one submit input" and what is my problem i cant get the value that is written into the generated inputs by user ... here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="generator"/>
    <input type="submit" name="generatingsubmit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['generator'])){
    $generator = $_POST['generator'];
    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
    for($i = 0; $i < $generator; $i++){
        echo "<input type='text' name='" . $i ."'/>";
    }
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'/>";
    echo "</form>";
}
    echo $_POST[$i];
?>
```

Comment: What is `$_POST['generator']` equal to? Could be being treated as a string, maybe try `$generator = (int)$_POST['generator'];`?

Comment: How do you know you don't get it?, I don't see any checks for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made index.php with the code:

```
    <form method="post" action="index.php?action=post">
    <input type="text" name="generator"/>
    <input type="submit" name="generatingsubmit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='post') {
    if(isset($_POST['generator'])){
    $generator = $_POST['generator'];
    echo "<form method='post' action='index.php?action=get_value'>";
    for($i = 0; $i < $generator; $i++){
        echo "<input type='text' name='somename[]'/><br />";
    }
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' />";
    echo "</form>";
    }
    }
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='get_value') {
    $somename=$_POST['somename'];
    foreach( $somename as $n ) {
      print $n;
    }

    }
    ?>
```

All works fine, inputs are generated then values of inputs are received.. All in one **index.php** file

Comment: Did you enter anything in the boxes afterwards to see if they'd echo something? Same here; nothing.

Comment: Your problem is that you can't get the values of the generated inputs?

Comment: It's not my question. I'm trying to find the OP a solution also, which I sort of have, but am having a problem with the `foreach(post)....` from the generated number of inputs and to echo their value entered in them.

Comment: Just write this code in some test index.php and you'll see the result.. Of course, If I understand your question correctly..

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.. sorry... ;)